# I can not add array from PDO to constructor PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I have probleme when i want add array from PDO to contructor of class news :

```
class News{

protected $erreurs = array(),
          $id,
          $auteur,
          $titre,
          $contenu;


 public function  __News(array $donnees){
         $this->hydrate($donnees);
     }

     public function hydrate(array $donnees)
     {
            foreach ($donnees as $key => $value)
        {
            $method = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
            if (method_exists($this, $method))
                   {
                       $this->$method($value);
                    }
        }
     }
```

Class Manager with function get news by id :

```
public function getUnique($id){
            $id = (int)$id;
            $sql = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, auteur, titre, contenu FROM news WHERE id = ?');
            $sql->bindParam('1', $id);
            $sql->execute();

            $mang = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
             return new News($mang);

        }
```

And index. php

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=new', 'root','');
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

    $manager = new Manager($db);



    $uniqueNews = $manager->getUnique(2);

    echo 'id : '.$uniqueNews->getAuteur();
```

But i don't know why the value of auteur do not display . If I'm going about this contructor completely wrong, please point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you setting `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` to `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`? Set it to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`

Comment: Ok. I will try with option PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION . Thanks you madara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your constructor should be called `__construct()`

```
class News{

      protected $erreurs = array(),
          $id,
          $auteur,
          $titre,
          $contenu;


     public function  __construct(array $donnees){
         $this->hydrate($donnees);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of a class should be either `__construct()` or a method named after the class. I prefer the first option. The second option is for legacy code.

```
class News{

    public function  __construct(array $donnees){
        // This is where your constructor code goes
    }
}
```